# Pass Canvas Image URL to another JSP

Tags: html5-canvas, parameter-passing

I am creating a Hand written image Digit recognizer. I have created an HTML canvas for users to draw a digit. When the user clicks on Predict button, the variable which stores `canvas.toDataURL` should be send to the server.

HTML code which displays 2 buttons, one for Save and one for Clear shown below:

```
   <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-default">Predict</button>
   <button type="button" id="clear" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
```

I have created a javascript for the id=save as:

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById("save");
saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveImage);
function saveImage(){
    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

I am unable to pass the variable 'data' to server. I can see the base64 encoded png format when I do a `window.open(data, '_blank', 'location=0, menubar=0');`. But thats not want I want. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're having problems with POSTing to the server, you should show the browser-side and server-side code you're using.